# Pinterest API to pull video pin stats

Tags: pinterest

Does Pinterest have any Public API to pull stats from video pins? I have gone through API docs and did not find anything.

Thanks,
Sourav

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't, but you can use the unofficial [py3-pinterest](https://github.com/bstoilov/py3-pinterest) client.

Python code:

```
import json

pin_data = load_pin_by_id(pin_id='148900331419819774')

print(json.dumps(pin_data))
```

[JSON response](https://pastebin.com/2m0VjFEU)